# Elasticsearch – Group by field name and count number of last event occurrences from each group

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-dsl

I am trying to get count of running and stopped processes based on indexed log messages.
In a relational database, I would have table and SQL query like this:

logs_tbl

```
| process_name  | process_status | timestamp        |
| ------------- | -------------- | ---------------- |
| p01           | Running        | 12/7/22 2:35 PM  |
| p02           | Running        | 12/7/22 2:35 PM  |
| p03           | Running        | 12/7/22 2:36 PM  |
| p04           | Running        | 12/7/22 2:36 PM  |
| p02           | Stopped        | 12/7/22 2:37 PM  |
| p04           |                | 12/7/22 2:39 PM  |
| p03           | Stopped        | 12/7/22 11:22 PM |
| p03           | Running        | 12/7/22 11:23 PM |
| p01           | Stopped        | 12/8/22 2:37 PM  |
```

```
SELECT logs_tbl.process_status, Count(logs_tbl.process_status) AS CountOfprocess_status 
FROM logs_tbl 
INNER JOIN (SELECT logs_tbl.process_name, MAX(logs_tbl.timestamp) AS last_time 
FROM logs_tbl 
WHERE logs_tbl.process_status Is Not Null GROUP BY logs_tbl.process_name)  AS t2 
ON (logs_tbl.timestamp = t2.last_time) AND (logs_tbl.process_name = t2.process_name) 
GROUP BY logs_tbl.process_status;
```

As a result, I will get:

```
Running 2
Stopped 2
```

In Elasticsearch, I have the following index mapping.

```
{
  "process_logs" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "@timestamp" : {
          "type" : "date"
        },
        "@version" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "process_attributes" : {
          "properties" : {
            "process_id" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "process_name" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "process_status" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And I tried the following DSL query:

```
GET /process_logs*/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "exists": {
      "field": "process_status"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "processes": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "process_attributes.process_name.keyword"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "last_status": {
          "max": {
            "field": "@timestamp"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As a result, I got:

```
  "aggregations" : {
    "processes" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "p1",
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "last_status" : {
            "value" : 1.66686408E12,
            "value_as_string" : "2022-10-27T09:48:00.000Z"
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "p2",
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "last_status" : {
            "value" : 1.666864149E12,
            "value_as_string" : "2022-10-27T09:49:09.000Z"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

At this moment I have the time of last status of each process, and I need to count different process_status types.

Any idea please.